# Solving for coprime integers

Tags: number-theory

I was working out some problems on brilliant.org and I stumbled across one that stumped me, the solution is rather straight forward however it relies on solving for co-prime numbers, which the solution doesn't really expand on.

[image]

$x$ and $y$ are co-prime due to the fact that the only number that can divide them into an integer is one. I'm stumped as to why $3z+2t=ex$ and more importantly the why $z-3t=ey$. Why is this the same $e$? Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Try using Latex, enclosing formulae in "$" works in most basic cases...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From $x(z-3t) = y(3z+2t)$, as no prime factor of $x$ divides $y$, they must all divide $3z+2t$, hence $x \mid 3z+2t$.  So let $3z+2t = e_1x$, similarly $z-3t = e_2y$.  Substituting we get $x \cdot e_2 y = y \cdot e_1x \implies e_1 = e_2 = e$ say...

Comment: Why do all the prime factors of x have to divide 3z+2t? Why can't we end up with a fraction?

Comment: Both sides are integers, in fact the same integer.  So both sides have the same prime factorisation. Now if $p \mid x$, it is there on the LHS, so it must also be in RHS, but it cannot be in $y$, so it has to be in $3z+2t$.

Comment: Why must both sides be integers?

Comment: To answer that we need the complete problem, not just the snippet you posted.  Where is this from, give the complete problem or at least full reference / link above.  If the sides aren't integer (i.e. $x, y, z, t$ aren't integer) then what do you mean by saying they are coprime?

Comment: Since both sides have to be integers the prime factors of x must divide $3z+2t$ leaving some constant left over, similarly when $z-3t$ is divided by y's prime factors the same constant must be left over. Right? yes all variables are integers https://brilliant.org/weekly-problems/2017-02-06/advanced/?p=2

Answer (score 0):

They simply use *Gauß' lemma*:

> Let $a,b,c$ be integers. If  $a$ divides $bc$ and is coprime to $b$, then $a$ divides $c$.

If you don't know this lemma,  here is a simple classic proof:

Since $a$ and $b$ are coprime, there's a *Bézout relation*:
$\;ua+vb=1$, whence 
$$ uac+vbc=c. $$
Now $a$ divides $uac$; it divides $bc$ by hypothesis, hence it divides $uac+vbc$=c.